# how to change osgi bundle status from installed to active?

Tags: maven, service, bundle, aem, invoke

I created a maven project in eclipse and installed the bundle in osgi console but the bundle is in Installed state. All the dependencies are reolved and there are no errors but still status is not active.
How to call the OSGI service from my AEM component page. Can i invoke the osgi service from my component jsp page only if bundle state is "active"? Do i need a ServiceID to be generated for my bundle for invoking the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

1. Tail your error logs
2. On browser goto `/system/console/bundles`
3. Search for you bundle and try activating it manually (use the play button on right side of  bundle entry)
4. If bundle is active successfully then possibly u need to fix you deploy script so it starts the bundle after installing
5. If bundle still doesn't start, look at the logs. There could be possible wiring issue or in case you have activator class for bundle its throwing exception while activating the bundle

Answer (score 0):

Please go to felix console and activate the bundle using play button . 
If still it doesn't get activated,expand the bundle there will be some error in the bundle(it will be shown in red).
So you need to resolve the class where the error is shown.

I hope this is helpful.

Thanks.